# Switching activities but keeping my variables

Tags: java, android, variables, android-activity

I am new to android development. I am making a basic tracking app for a card game I play. I need two activities to track 2 different sets of variables. My question is no matter what I do the variables reset themselves. I just need to either store the variables when I switch activities or just pause and resume the activities. Here is the code for switching my activities. How can I switch between the 2 constantly, without loosing the variables in both activities.

Method in main Activity is first...

```
public void showPWActivity(){    
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Planeswalker.class);    
    startActivity(myIntent);    
}
```

Method for the second activity

```
public void showMainActivity() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: I suggest add more details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**To save state of your variables before pausing the activity using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):**

```
    // Access the default SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences preferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // The SharedPreferences editor - must use commit() to submit changes
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    // Edit the saved preferences
    editor.putString("Name", "Tom");
    editor.putInt("Age", 31);
    editor.commit();
```

Get state of your variables when resuming your activity:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String Name = preferences.getString("Name","Default");
```

**To pass data between activities:**

In your current Activity, create a new [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values. Here we are retrieving a String

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

Use this technique to pass variables from one Activity to the other.

Answer (score -1):

there is more then one way accomplish this. the most simple is overriding the onRestoreInstanceState, and onSaveInstanceState

look here 
http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/saving-the-activity-s-instance-state-a-tutorial.html

and 
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

    final EditText textBox = 
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    CharSequence userText = textBox.getText();
    outState.putCharSequence("savedText", userText);

}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {      
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");

    final EditText textBox = 
           (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    CharSequence userText = 
           savedState.getCharSequence("savedText");

    textBox.setText(userText);
}
```

for more complex things consider making a service in the background witch will save all the data you need for your application.

---

> To save state of your variables before pausing the activity using
>   SharedPreferences

you do not! save your data to local storage(SharedPreferences = storing data to the HD), as long as you do not really have to do this(config you have to store even after you close your app), just as you do not store data to your H.D drive in your desktop apps, as long as it is not what you really need.